# What can destroy a $_SESSION variable php?

Tags: php, session, model-view-controller

I am working on a webapp in php, and my session keeps getting destroyed on only certain views of my application and I can't seem to find out why. I can't upload all the code here because there is too much, so I want to know what can destroy a session and I will look for the problem. 
The weird part is that it happens inbetween two views, for example it fully loads the first view with no problem (I checked with echo statements at the end of that view to make sure it was still active) and when I click on a link the session variable is destroyed before loading the next view.

Comment: Have you started session on every page using `session_start();` ??

Comment: yes it is in the constructor of the controller which has to be called if a page is to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `session_destroy();`-function to destroy the whole session (and all `$_SESSION`-values with it) or you can the `unset`-function to destroy a value by key as if `$_SESSION` was an array.

Answer (score 0):

Make always sure you're using `session_start()` the right way. On top on every page you are using the sessions. The session keeps destroying because the session was never made. To make it work, be sure you have set up the session start like this example:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Be on top
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- The rest of your page
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

if it happened only on certain view, is there any session unset or session destroy? and maybe you need to add session_start() on controller which have those view (linked). (read also https://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/ about session_start section )

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy ALL the session array :

`session_destroy();`

Or only unset some parts :

```
unset($_SESSION('your_thing']);
```

An other way is to put empty some parts of the array:

```
$_SESSION['your_thing'] ='';
```

All are correct, but if you destroy all the session, on the next page you have to set session_start(); if you want use session, but you 'll lose all informations.

the best way is to use unset  or empty the array ...